# Get checksum of directory, whilst excluding a particular child directory in Bash

Tags: bash, checksum

Suppose one has a folder structure:

```
some_dir/a.txt
some_dir/b.txt
some_dir/c/d.txt
some_dir/.e/f.txt
some_dir/.e/g.txt
```

How could one get the checksum (e.g. md5sum, or sha256), of:

```
some_dir/a.txt
some_dir/b.txt
some_dir/c/d.txt
```

Whilst excluding all contents in `some_dir/.e/` in the computation of the checksum?

Comment: Use `find ... -not path ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
find some_dir -type f \! -path '*/.*' -exec md5sum {} +
```